# Unable to authenticate the login of application user using Keycloak

Tags: java, reactjs, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I am working over integration of React application with Keycloak. I have installed the Keycloak server version 11.0.2 over my local machine. I am able to access the administrative login and create the admin user. I have also created a custom client and user with credentials using the Keycloak. My react application is hosted over port 9000 of my machine and Keycloak over 8080 (default) port. Now, when I am redirecting to my application URL it is automatically redirecting to the below URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/{Custom_realm}/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id={Custom_Client}&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2F&state=r8yy83fdgd-27f8-4aa9-a679-01sfdsgd9&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=27fedfgf89-66be-4484-bbcc-aabb4saddc4
```

[image]

URL is rendering the login page without the CSS. Not sure why the CSS is not getting rendered.
Also it is not authenticating and giving error

> Cannot POST /realms/{Realm}/login-actions/authenticate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keycloak redirecting to login page because keycloak application url check user logged in or not before redirecting to application.

To debug your login page rendering without css need to know what changes you have done in that realm theme setting from admin and server themes folder because in default keycloak 11.0.2 it's rendering with css.

Tried to hit POST /authenticate from postman and browser it's working for me.

Authenticate working CURL REQUEST:

`curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/test/login-actions/authenticate?session_code=pmE8VZtaYo4u5IN7vOQ_OLh9Ft_n-pftbBqzk9T2z-k&execution=7d28dd8f-6436-4280-a1da-51cbca5084c1&client_id=account&tab_id=hdEKLv2DNPg' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \ --header 'Cookie: AUTH_SESSION_ID_LEGACY=16e87095-05df-4ca2-88c6-e0c7e2cf6199.milan-latitude-e5450; KEYCLOAK_SESSION_LEGACY=test/0805f781-d0e3-42cf-b34c-be110547d48c/16e87095-05df-4ca2-88c6-e0c7e2cf6199; KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY_LEGACY=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI5YmMwNGZkOS1kZDQ3LTRhZmUtOWM1NC0wZWQ1NGFmMmU1MWIifQ.eyJleHAiOjE2MDE1NjYxMjksImlhdCI6MTYwMTUzMDEyOSwianRpIjoiYmJmNmE4ZmQtYzBjMi00MWQxLWJkMGEtY2MwZmVmNmViMzYxIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgwL2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL3Rlc3QiLCJzdWIiOiIwODA1Zjc4MS1kMGUzLTQyY2YtYjM0Yy1iZTExMDU0N2Q0OGMiLCJ0eXAiOiJTZXJpYWxpemVkLUlEIiwic2Vzc2lvbl9zdGF0ZSI6IjE2ZTg3MDk1LTA1ZGYtNGNhMi04OGM2LWUwYzdlMmNmNjE5OSIsInN0YXRlX2NoZWNrZXIiOiIxV0pWUUN5cDRfcEJJQzZpNENRWnZKMzk2aFBhREdoYmNjWXlDT3VTUm13In0.bteyEEAhIWzbi2MdJAwp9ndCXsTPtjHiGBtMYUglWR0; oauth2_authentication_csrf_insecure=MTYwMDc3ODA2MnxEdi1CQkFFQ180SUFBUkFCRUFBQVB2LUNBQUVHYzNSeWFXNW5EQVlBQkdOemNtWUdjM1J5YVc1bkRDSUFJRFZoTlRaaU1qWTJZVEF6TWpRMk1HUmhaV0pqWWpJNU5UbGtOekl5TURRMXwGvq0FY6TUmmWfUmzaDwnTBf9KC-1Ni5N5pc4IXVcBIQ==; oauth2_consent_csrf_insecure=MTYwMDc3ODIzNXxEdi1CQkFFQ180SUFBUkFCRUFBQVB2LUNBQUVHYzNSeWFXNW5EQVlBQkdOemNtWUdjM1J5YVc1bkRDSUFJRGt3T0RCaVlXSTFZVFJqTVRSbE5HTTVaREUxWldZMFptTTVaREl5TUdNeXxmdLHoVF_3zSxhHR8F2zez-Q37wde7ZnPkb_wt_o-T9g==' \ --data-urlencode 'username=milan' \ --data-urlencode 'password=password'`

Comment: Thanks Milan for the inputs. But I am using the default theme of keycloak css. Infact when the theme was not getting rendered I selected the "Keycloak" theme from the master realm and custom realm

Comment: Can you mention steps of your keycloak 11.0.2 installation, realm and user creation to regenerate issue in my local keycloak.

Comment: Sure.1)  I installed keycloack server using the https://www.keycloak.org/downloads.html and downloaded the server Zip sha1 version . Then I ran standalone.bat over cmd prompt to run the keycloak server over the url http://localhost:8080.  2) I clicked on administrative console and created admin user with credentials. 3) Then I logged on to the admin user 4) it landed me into  http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/master/console/#/realms/master 5) Then I created a realm named UI_Realm and a client UI_Client 6) Root url :lhttp://localhost:9000

Comment: 7) Valid redirect URI : http://localhost:9000/* 8)web Origins:  *  9 ) created user : by giving username 10) user enabled :On 11) under credentials tab : gave credentials by setting temporary off  12) Now I am trying to hit down from the app url http://localhost:9000

Comment: Are you able to login to keycloak UI_Realm using this url http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/UI_Realm/account/ ?

Comment: No.   Cannot GET /realms/UI_Realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth

Comment: As you are not able to login with http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/UI_Realm/account/ there is something wrong in keycloak installation.

I am not able to reproduce issue by your steps. Mentioning steps for keycloak installation in linux(as i don't have windows machine):
1. Downladed keycloak server 11.0.2 zip sha1 from https://www.keycloak.org/downloads.html.
2. Unzip file using cmd:  unzip keycloak-11.0.2.zip
3. To start server go to keycloak-11.0.2 directory in run command bin/standalone.sh
4.  Created admin user and logged in using admin.
5. Created realm name UI_Realm.

Comment: Are you using any authentication token explicitly ?? The steps you have stated uptill UI_Realm are similar to one I have followed

Comment: 6. In admin login, switch to UI_realm by top left side dropdown.
7. Created user by username.
8. Under cred tab: set cred by setting temporary off.
9. Go to clients tab: click on base url next to account.
10. Now it is displaying login screen with css.
11. Logged in using username and password(created in step 7 and 8).

Comment: No i am not using authentication token explicitly. Only configured as mentioned till step 11. Your basic account login to UI_Realm needed to work before configuration of any client(React app).

Comment: What is the value of base url you are setting ? as part of step 9 by going into clients tab Is this the app url? or key cloak url

Comment: It's keycloak url. I am not setting any value of base url. It's default client config created by keycloak when you create new realm.

Just one suggestion if you don't have any requirement for keycloak development and you are familiar to docker then use keycloak docker image. No need to debug keycloak installation in your environment.
Keycloak Docker image by redhat : https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak

Comment: Hey Milan I am able to view the account using url http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/UI_Realm/account . CSS is getting populated for user login popup upon hitting the url of the application. However, it is giving error Invalid parameter: redirect_uri. Did you set any redirect uri in the client created by you?

Comment: In valid redirect uri field of your react app client setting in keycloak you need to add uri of your react app to which redirection needed to be done.

Comment: Milan, How did you handle logout from your application? what was the url you were using for logging out of the application.

Comment: I have done development on keycloak not in application. Let me know first which protocol(SAML/OAUTH/OPENID) your application is using so based on it i can help you with logout.

Answer (score 5):

I made the mistake of setting "Realm Settings" -> "General" -> "Frontend URL" to the homepage URL of the application the realm was for.

Don't do that.

Emptying that field and saving it resolved the issue for me.